# Using Nginx and Ocelot Api together

Tags: docker, nginx, ocelot

I want to publish my net core application in my docker-compose file on Ubuntu. Would it be unreasonable to use Nginx for SSL forwarding and Ocelot api for api gateway together ? Thank you very much in advance.